# Bash script for opening screens and compiling the same file

Tags: shell-script, compiling, zsh, gnu-screen

I have written a bash script to initiate separate screen sessions and run a command in each of them that compiles the same `C++` source file in `ROOT` (an object-oriented data analysis framework http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/about) in every screen session. It worked fine at the beginning; however as the compilation time increased(as an observation) it failed to compile and numerous errors were produced. The error message inside the text file is below:

```
Info in <TUnixSystem::ACLiC>: creating shared library /DIRECTORY/./readerSummerStd_C.so
ACLiC:0: RuntimeWarning: Failed to generate the dependency file for /DIRECTORY/./readerSummerStd_C.so
Note: Link requested for already precompiled class map<string,int,less<string>,allocator<pair<const string,int> > > (ignore this message) :0:
g++: /DIRECTORY/readerSummerStd_C_ACLiC_dict.o: No such file or directory
Error in <ACLiC>: Compilation failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./NEWrunReader.py", line 87, in <module>
    from ROOT import readerSummerStd as reader
ImportError: cannot import name readerSummerStd
```

The analysis zsh script is provided below for reference, if I wait for one code to compile and then run the other code no problem occurs. How can I circumvent this problem?

```
    #! /bin/zsh
    ### Script for running everything in screens ###
    echo You have the following screens running:
    screen -ls
    echo Press any key to proceed. NOTE THAT YOUR OTHER SCREENS WILL GET KILLED!
    read
    pkill -15 -U arisevon screen ## We make sure that no screens are running for now
    bkgarr=(TopJets BosonJets DiBoson TTbar)
    sigarr=(NM1 NM2 NM3 Scenario4 Scenario6)
    puarr=(50PU 140PU)
    lumarr=(30 300 3000)

    echo Please type 1 for 50PU samples and 2 for 140PU samples
    read PU
    if [[ $PU -ne 1 && $PU -ne 2 ]] ; then
        echo You have to enter 1 or 2
        return 1
    fi

    echo Please type 1 for 300fb-1 and 2 for 3000fb-1
    read lum

    if [[ $lum -ne 1 && $lum -ne 2 ]] ; then
        echo You have to enter 1 or 2
        return 1
    fi

    if [ $PU = 1 ]; then
        let "lum = $lum + 1"
        #echo $lum
    fi

    ex NEWrunReader.py  <<EOEX
      :43s/Lumi.*/Lumi=$lumarr[lum]/
      :x
    EOEX

    echo Press any key to proceed or Ctrl+C to abort!
    read
    for index in $bkgarr
    do
        screen -dmS $index
        screen -S $index -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
        screen -S $index -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$index >& $index.txt &"$'\r'
    done
    for sigind in $sigarr
    do
        screen -dmS $sigind
        screen -S $sigind -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
        screen -S $sigind -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$sigind >& $sigind.txt &"$'\r'
    done
    return 0
```

These codes are for performing an analysis in high energy physics and I am really curious as this script worked flawlessly before. The only difference is that there is that the C++ source code got more complex than before. The Python code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
from ROOT import gROOT

# scenarios and samples
scenarios = ['NoPU','50PU','140PU']
#scenarios = ['140PU']
########################################################
# FOR THE PAPER (SNOWMASS)
#samples   = ['DiBoson','BosonJets','TopJets','TTbar','TDR4','TDR5','TDR6','TDR8','naturalSUSY']
########################################################
#samples   = ['TTbar']
# by historic reason we have as dir names: bjets  diboson  tdr tdrNew tjets  ttbar for snowmass
# by historic reason we have as dir names: bjets  diboson  tdr        tjets  ttbar for snowmass2
#for (ecfa) PhaseII_C3 / C4v2
########################################################
#samples w.o weight (snowmass)
#noWeight  = ['TDR4','TDR5','TDR6','TDR8','naturalSUSY']

# nTuple input path
#########################################################
# for susyhit
samples   = ['DiBoson','BosonJets','TopJets','TTbar','NM1','NM2','NM3','Scenario6','Scenario4','Scenario1']
noWeight  = ['NM1','NM2','NM3','Scenario6','Scenario4','Scenario1']
base = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Output/EOSforFutureStudies/14TeV/PhaseII/Configuration4v2/140PileUp'
#########################################################
# for naturalSUSY
#base = 'nTuples/ECFA/PhaseII_C3'
#base = 'nTuples/ECFA/PhaseII_C4'
#########################################################
# FOR THE PAPER (SNOWMASS)
#base = 'nTuples/snowmass2'
#########################################################
# for PhaseII_C3 & PhaseII_C4v2 (ecfa) #################  !!!!!!!!! #####################
#base = 'Output/ECFA/PhaseII_C3' #### noch per Hand aendern, besser in scenarios C3, C4 beruecksichtigen! ####
#base = 'Output/ECFA/PhaseII_C4v2'
#base = 'Output/14TeV/'
#
#
# lumi in fb^-1
Lumi=30


def help():
    print 'First argument analysis:'
    print '   SingleS'
    print ' then a list of inputs - read the code'
    sys.exit(0)

from operator import mul
def scale(fac,list):
    return map(mul,len(list)*[fac],list)

# choose the analysis and a sample
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    if sys.argv[1]=='SingleS':       # single lepton  stop - CMS
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSingleS.C+')
        from ROOT import readerSingleS as reader
    if sys.argv[1]=='Claudia_task':       # single lepton  stop - CMS
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerClaudia_task.C+')
        from ROOT import readerClaudia_task as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='Skeleton':  # SKELETON
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSkeleton.C+')
        from ROOT import readerSkeleton as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='SingleSOld':  # single lepton testing version 
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSingleSOld.C+')
        from ROOT import readerSingleSOld as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='SingleS_P':  # single lepton testing version 
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSingleS_P.C+')
        from ROOT import readerSingleS_P as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='SingleSDelphMET':  # single lepton testing version 
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSingleSDelphMET.C+')
        from ROOT import readerSingleSDelphMET as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='EWKino':  # EWKino
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerEWKino.C+') # used to be EWKinoNew
        from ROOT import readerEWKino as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='AtlasH_Sb':  # Exc
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerAtlasH_Sb.C+') # used to be EXc
        from ROOT import readerAtlasH_Sb as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='AtlasH':  # Atlas hadronic
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerAtlasH.C+') # used to be ?????
        from ROOT import readerAtlasH as reader
    elif sys.argv[1]=='SummerStd':  #
        gROOT.LoadMacro('readerSummerStd.C+') # used to be ?????
        from ROOT import readerSummerStd as reader
    else: 
        help()
else: 
    help()


#prepare empty dictionaries
do={}
for scene in scenarios:
    do[scene]={}
    for samp in samples:
        do[scene][samp] = 0
# read input line and set flags what to process
flag=False
for e in sys.argv:
    for scene in scenarios:
        for samp in samples:
            if e==scene+'_'+samp: 
                do[scene][samp] = 1
                if scene=='140PU': Lumi=Lumi*10  # lumi*10 for 140PU
                flag=True
if not flag: help()


# prepare empty dictionaries
dirsHT={}
inDir={}
weights={}
for scene in scenarios:
    inDir[scene]={}
#   weights[scene]={}


### for PhaseII_C3 / C4v2 ((from ecfa)) ONLY TTbar



#--------------------------------------------- sample properties for processing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
#                                               I:  HT dirs, xsecs --> 33TeV
#                                              II:  HT dirs, xsecs --> 14TeV
#------------------------------------------------ diboson
# HT dirs 
#I:dirsHT['DiBoson']  = ['0-400/','400-1000/','1000-2000/','2000-3400/','3400-100000/']
dirsHT['DiBoson']  = ['0-300/','300-700/','700-1300/','1300-2100/','2100-100000/']
#    xsec
#I:weights['DiBoson'] = [776.00399, 106.85023, 10.16835, 0.86136, 0.09507]
weights['DiBoson'] = [249.97710, 35.23062, 4.13743, 0.41702, 0.04770]
#    multiply all by lumi
weights['DiBoson'] = scale(Lumi,weights['DiBoson'])
#
# NoPU
inDir['NoPU']['DiBoson']  = base+'/NoPU/diboson/'
# 50PU
inDir['50PU']['DiBoson']  = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/diboson/' 
# 140PU
#inDir['140PU']['DiBoson'] = base+'/diboson/'

inDir['140PU']['DiBoson'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/1st_Output/PhaseII_140PU_ProdJul28/diboson/'
#'/140PU/diboson/'
#
#------------------------------------------------ boson+jets
# HT dirs 
#I:dirsHT['BosonJets']  = ['0-400/','400-1000/','1000-1800/','1800-3000/','3000-4600/','4600-6600/','6600-100000/']
dirsHT['BosonJets']  = ['0-300/','300-600/','600-1100/','1100-1800/','1800-2700/','2700-3700/','3700-100000/']
#    xsec
#I:weights['BosonJets'] = [129824.79383, 6598.37529, 325.55814, 32.45249, 3.16778, 0.32737, 0.04045]
weights['BosonJets'] = [34409.92339, 2642.85309, 294.12311, 25.95000, 2.42111, 0.22690, 0.02767]
#    multiply all by lumi
weights['BosonJets'] = scale(Lumi,weights['BosonJets'])
#
# NoPU
inDir['NoPU']['BosonJets']  = base+'/NoPU/bjets/'
# 50PU
inDir['50PU']['BosonJets']  = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/bjets/' 
# 140PU
inDir['140PU']['BosonJets'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseII_140PU_ProdJul28/bjets/'
#inDir['140PU']['BosonJets'] ='/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Output/EOSforFutureStudies/14TeV/PhaseII/Configuration4v2/140PileUp/bjets/'
#inDir['140PU']['BosonJets'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Output/delphes/ProdJun14/bjets/'
#base+'/bjets/'
#'/140PU/bjets/'
#
#---------------------------------------------- ttbar
# HT dirs 
#I:dirsHT['TTbar']  = ['0-600/','600-1200/','1200-2000/','2000-3200/','3200-4800/','4800-100000/']
dirsHT['TTbar']  = ['0-600/','600-1100/','1100-1700/','1700-2500/','2500-100000/']
#    xsec
#I:weights['TTbar'] = [3438.70635, 505.82210, 61.81892, 7.65752, 0.72643, 0.07147]
weights['TTbar'] = [530.89358, 42.55351, 4.48209, 0.52795, 0.05449]
#    multiply all by lumi
weights['TTbar'] = scale(Lumi,weights['TTbar'])
#
# NoPU
inDir['NoPU']['TTbar']  = base+'/NoPU/ttbar/'
# 50PU
inDir['50PU']['TTbar']  = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/clseitz/Delphes/FILES/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/ttbar/' 
# 140PU
inDir['140PU']['TTbar'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseII_140PU_ProdJul28/ttbar/'
#inDir['140PU']['TTbar'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Output/delphes/ProdJun14/ttbar/'
#inDir['140PU']['TTbar'] = base+'/ttbar/'
#'/140PU/ttbar/'
#
#--------------------------------------------- tjets
# HT dirs 
#I:dirsHT['TopJets']  = ['0-600/','600-1200/','1200-2200/','2200-3600/','3600-100000/']
dirsHT['TopJets']  = ['0-500/','500-1000/','1000-1600/','1600-2400/','2400-100000/']
#    xsec
#I:weights['TopJets'] = [493.50469, 23.51848, 1.97369, 0.13199, 0.01099]
weights['TopJets'] = [109.73602, 5.99325, 0.37680, 0.03462, 0.00312]
#    multiply all by lumi
weights['TopJets'] = scale(Lumi,weights['TopJets'])
#
# NoPU
inDir['NoPU']['TopJets']  = base+'/NoPU/tjets/'
# 50PU
inDir['50PU']['TopJets']  = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/clseitz/Delphes/FILES/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/tjets/' 
# 140PU
inDir['140PU']['TopJets'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/t/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/Output/PhaseII_140PU_ProdJul28/tjets/'
#inDir['140PU']['TopJets'] = base+'/tjets/'
#'/140PU/tjets/'
#---------------------------------------------STCs
# HT dirs - none for STC samples
#dirsHT['TDR4'] = ['/']
#dirsHT['TDR5'] = ['/']
#dirsHT['TDR6'] = ['/']
#dirsHT['TDR8'] = ['/']
# naturalSUSY
#dirsHT['naturalSUSY'] = ['/']
# susyhit
dirsHT['Scenario1'] = ['/']
dirsHT['Scenario4'] = ['/']
dirsHT['Scenario6'] = ['/']
dirsHT['NM1'] = ['/']
dirsHT['NM2'] = ['/']
dirsHT['NM3'] = ['/']

# xsec - we multiply by lumi   xsec*k-factor*Lumi calculated with parse.py: values for 33 TeV with 140 Pile Up
# 33TeV 
#weights['TDR4'] = [68.31*1.3626*Lumi]    # values for ? 14 TeV      #12.80 
#weights['TDR5'] = [19.08*1.4105*Lumi]                               # 3.82
#weights['TDR6'] = [10.87*1.4438*Lumi]                               # 2.53
#weights['TDR8'] = [ 7.777*1.4917*Lumi]                              # 2.19
# 14TeV ####### wrong ##########
#weights['TDR4'] = [9.060*1.3626*Lumi]      # values for ? 14 TeV     #12.80 
#weights['TDR5'] = [4.299*1.4105*Lumi]                                # 3.82
#weights['TDR6'] = [2.039*1.4438*Lumi]                                # 2.53
#weights['TDR8'] = [1.788*1.4917*Lumi]                                # 2.19
# 14TeV
weights['TDR4'] = [12.80*Lumi] 
weights['TDR5'] = [3.82*Lumi]  
weights['TDR6'] = [2.53*Lumi]  
weights['TDR8'] = [2.19*Lumi]
weights['naturalSUSY'] = [1.211*Lumi]
# susyhit
weights['Scenario1'] = [2.52*Lumi]
weights['Scenario4'] = [0.009635*Lumi] 
weights['Scenario6'] = [2.52*Lumi] 
#weights['Scenario6'] = [2.19*Lumi] 
weights['NM1'] = [0.15*Lumi] 
weights['NM2'] = [0.07*Lumi] 
weights['NM3'] = [1.1*Lumi] 
#
bit=''
if base=='nTuples/snowmass/':bit='New' 
# NoPU
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR4'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr/'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR5'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr/'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR6'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr/'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR8'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr/'+bit+'/8/'
# 50PU
#inDir['50PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/50PU/tdr/'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/50PU/tdr/'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/50PU/tdr/'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/50PU/tdr/'+bit+'/8/'
# 140PU
#inDir['140PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/140PU/tdr/'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/140PU/tdr/'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/140PU/tdr/'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/140PU/tdr/'+bit+'/8/'
#
############## susyhit ############################
#inDir['140PU']['Scenario1'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Ntuple/STC_Third/'
inDir['140PU']['Scenario4'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseII_140PU_ProdJul28/Ntuple/STOC'
inDir['140PU']['Scenario6'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/Output/stc/READY/'
inDir['140PU']['NM1'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/Output/naturalModel/1/READY/'
inDir['140PU']['NM2'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/Output/naturalModel/2/READY/'
inDir['140PU']['NM3'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/trippk/dust/AN_PAS_TP/DELPHES/nTUPLER/batch/Output/naturalModel/3/READY/'

inDir['50PU']['NM1'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/NM1/'
inDir['50PU']['NM2'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/NM2/'
inDir['50PU']['NM3'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/NM3/'
inDir['50PU']['Scenario4'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/STOC/' 
inDir['50PU']['Scenario6'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/s/safarzad/dust/Output/delphes/PhaseI_50PU_ProdAug6/STC/'
#inDir['140PU']['Scenario6'] = '/afs/desy.de/user/t/trippk/dust/snowmass/NewTupler_topness/Batch/Output/14TeV/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1/8'
#inDir['140PU']['NM1'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Ntuple/NM1/'
#inDir['140PU']['NM2'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Ntuple/NM2/'
#inDir['140PU']['NM3'] = '/nfs/dust/cms/user/safarzad/Delphes/nTupler_topness/Batch/Ntuple/NM3/'
####################################################
################# naturalSUSY ######################
####################################################
# 140PU
#inDir['140PU']['naturalSUSY'] = 'Output/naturalSUSY/14TeV/140PU/PhaseII_conf3/'
#inDir['140PU']['naturalSUSY'] = 'Output/naturalSUSY/14TeV/140PU/PhaseII_conf4/'
#
# NoPU 3.0.10
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR4'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR5'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR6'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR8'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/8/'
#3.0.10 - 3.0.9.1
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR4'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR5'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR6'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR8'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
#3.0.9.1 
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR4'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR5'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR6'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['NoPU']['TDR8'] = base+'/NoPU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
#
#
# 50PU 3.0.10
#inDir['50PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/8/'
# 50PU 3.0.10 - 3.0.9.1
#inDir['50PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
# 50PU 3.0.9.1
#inDir['50PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['50PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/50PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
#
#
# 140PU 3.0.10
#inDir['140PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.10'+bit+'/8/'
# 140PU 3.0.10 - 3.0.9.1
#inDir['140PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.10_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
# 140PU 3.0.9.1
#print  base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR4'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/4/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR5'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/5/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR6'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/6/'
#inDir['140PU']['TDR8'] = base+'/140PU/tdr_delphes3.0.9.1_card3.0.9.1'+bit+'/8/'
#--------------------------------------------- end of sample properties

from ROOT import TFile
from glob import glob
from sys import exit
def GetEntries(dirname):
    files = glob(dirname+'/*nTuple.root')
    if len(files)>1:
        print 'GetEntries: there is more than 1 root file in '+dirname
        exit(0)
    print dirname,files
    file=TFile(files[0])
    tree = file.Get("delphTree")
    return tree.GetEntries()

# do it
for scene in scenarios:
    for samp in samples:
        if do[scene][samp]: 
            f=''
            print dirsHT, samp
            for i in range(len(dirsHT[samp])):
                entries = GetEntries(inDir[scene][samp]+dirsHT[samp][i])
                f=f+inDir[scene][samp]+dirsHT[samp][i]+' '+str(weights[samp][i]/entries)+' '
            print f,samp,scene
            if samp in noWeight:
                reader(f,scene+'_'+samp,False)
            else:   
                reader(f,scene+'_'+samp)
```

Comment: did you check if the more complex Cpp script compiles fine as standalone? If not, can you check that?

Comment: You've provided a `zsh` script that calls a Python script. Where's the Bash script? What does the Python script do?

Comment: @Simply_Me Yes it compiles by itself.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Sorry there is only a `zsh` script the Python script compiles and import the `C++` source file into `ROOT` analysis program.

Comment: I don't use ROOT, but it looks like simultaneous multiple compilations of the same C++ file in the same directory is going to cause problems.  Maybe there's some sort of locking mechanism that can be used to serialize compilations. You might try asking over on Stack Overflow; there's a [root-framework] tag there for ROOT.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the answer, can I directly migrate this question to Stack Overflow from here?

Comment: I don't know if askers can migrate questions themselves. Usually moderators do it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks anyway, I already posted it in Stack Exchange.